# Unable to run analysis on SonarQube after upgrade to version 6.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I’m trying to run the analysis on SonarQube 6.2 using MSBuild scanner but I'm receiving an error immediately on the first C# file analyzed.
The error occurs also on a very simple test solution containing only two C# files.
The error is the following:

```
SonarAnalyzer for C# version 1.20.1.1275
0/2 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\TF\16\35\src\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs
Failed to analyze the file: C:\TF\16\35\src\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\TF\16\35\src\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs' is denied.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.CompilationHelper.GetSolutionFromFiles(String filePath, Encoding encoding, AnalyzerLanguage language)
    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.Program.RunAnalysis(ScannerAnalyzerConfiguration conf)
```

The analysis was working fine before the upgrade. The user used to run the analysis has full rights on all files to be analyzed. The files do not appear to be locked before the analysis.
I'm using the following configuration:

- SonarQube v. 6.2
- C# Plugin v 5.5.1.522
- Sonar scanner for MsBuild v2.2.0.24

Here the full scanner log:

```
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
Default properties file was found at C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
Removing the existing directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube
Creating directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube
SonarQube server URL: http://**server***:9000
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
10:40:36.698  Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
10:40:36.713  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'
10:40:36.715  Updating build integration targets...
10:40:36.72  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\Users\**user***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
10:40:36.721  Installed SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\Users\**user***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\12.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore
10:40:36.724  Installed SonarQube.Integration.targets to C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\bin\targets
10:40:36.726  Creating config and output folders...
10:40:36.726  Creating directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\conf
10:40:36.727  Creating directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out
10:40:36.736  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
10:40:36.745  Fetching properties for project 'TestSonarQube:MAIN' from http://**server***:9000/api/properties?resource=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN...
10:40:36.746  Downloading from http://**server***:9000/api/properties?resource=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN...
10:40:37.514  Downloading from http://**server***:9000/api/updatecenter/installed_plugins...
10:40:37.575  Fetching quality profile for project 'TestSonarQube:MAIN' from http://**server***:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search?projectKey=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN...
10:40:37.575  Downloading from http://**server***:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search?projectKey=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN...
10:40:37.755  Downloading from http://**server***:9000/api/rules/search?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&ps=500&activation=true&qprofile=cs-sonar-way-15151&p=1...
10:40:37.898  No active rules for cs
10:40:37.953  Pre-processing succeeded.
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
Default properties file was found at C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
10:40:39.425  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
10:40:39.428  Not running under TeamBuild
10:40:39.428  Analysis base directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube
Build directory: 
Bin directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\bin
Config directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\conf
Output directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out
Config file: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml
Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
The supplied Code Analysis ErrorLog file is a valid json file and does not need to be fixed: C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\bin\Debug\SampleProjectForAnalysis.exe.RoslynCA.json
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Users\**user***\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\SampleProjectForAnalysis.csproj
Setting analysis property: sonar.visualstudio.enable=false
Writing processing summary to C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is already set. Value: -Xmx2048m
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
Overwriting the value of environment variable 'SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS'. Old value: -Xmx2048m, new value: -Xmx2048m
Executing file C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\sonar-scanner-2.8\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
  Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties 
  Working directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar
  Timeout (ms):-1
  Process id: 17152
C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\sonar-scanner-2.8\bin\..
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\sonar-scanner-2.8\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
10:40:40.025 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
10:40:40.031 INFO: Java 1.8.0_101 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
10:40:40.032 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
10:40:40.032 INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
10:40:40.345 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
10:40:40.346 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
10:40:40.346 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
10:40:40.346 DEBUG: init keystore
10:40:40.347 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
10:40:40.575 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\**user***\.sonar\cache
10:40:40.575 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
10:40:40.583 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
10:40:40.584 DEBUG: Download: http://**server***:9000/batch_bootstrap/index
10:40:40.701 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
10:40:40.702 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
10:40:40.715 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
10:40:40.753 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
10:40:40.754 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
10:40:40.764 DEBUG: Execution start
10:40:41.295 DEBUG: Publish global mode
10:40:41.454 INFO: Load global repositories
10:40:41.635 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/batch/global | time=176ms
10:40:41.729 INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=276ms
10:40:41.754 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\**user***\.sonar\cache
10:40:42.059 INFO: Load plugins index
10:40:42.071 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=12ms
10:40:42.071 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=12ms
10:40:42.073 DEBUG: Load plugins
10:40:42.093 DEBUG: Load plugins (done) | time=20ms
10:40:42.110 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin ***custom*** Analyzer [***custom***codeanalysiscsharp] (built with API lower than 5.2)
10:40:42.112 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin TFVC [scmtfvc] (built with API lower than 5.2)
10:40:42.403 DEBUG: Plugins:
10:40:42.404 DEBUG:   * C# 5.5.1.522 (csharp)
10:40:42.404 DEBUG:   * ***custom*** Analyzer 1.0.0.4 (***custom***codeanalysiscsharp)
10:40:42.404 DEBUG:   * LDAP 2.1.0.507 (ldap)
10:40:42.404 DEBUG:   * JavaScript 2.19.0.3866 (javascript)
10:40:42.405 DEBUG:   * TFVC 2.1.2 (scmtfvc)
10:40:42.426 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
10:40:42.427 INFO: SonarQube server 6.2
10:40:42.427 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
10:40:42.428 DEBUG: Work directory: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
10:40:42.429 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
10:40:42.429 DEBUG: Execution execute
10:40:43.192 INFO: Process project properties
10:40:43.206 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=15ms
10:40:43.320 INFO: Load project repositories
10:40:43.791 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN | time=469ms
10:40:43.904 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=584ms
10:40:43.980 DEBUG: Available languages:
10:40:43.980 DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
10:40:43.980 DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
10:40:43.984 INFO: Load quality profiles
10:40:44.039 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=TestSonarQube%3AMAIN | time=54ms
10:40:44.045 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=61ms
10:40:44.050 INFO: Load active rules
10:40:44.097 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=cs-sonar-way-15151&p=1&ps=500 | time=46ms
10:40:44.169 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=js-sonar-way-47608&p=1&ps=500 | time=49ms
10:40:44.176 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=126ms
10:40:44.251 INFO: Publish mode
10:40:44.251 DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
10:40:44.253 INFO: -------------  Scan SampleProjectForAnalysis
10:40:44.393 INFO: Load server rules
10:40:44.610 DEBUG: GET 200 http://**server***:9000/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=217ms
10:40:44.632 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=239ms
10:40:44.695 DEBUG: Initializers : GenericCoverageSensor
10:40:44.696 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor
10:40:44.696 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor (done) | time=0ms
10:40:44.697 INFO: Base dir: C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube
10:40:44.697 INFO: Working dir: C:\**root path***\Sonar\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\TestSonarQube_MAIN_TestSonarQube_MAIN_F1F49A3C-2CDE-4DC2-943C-BDE756CF7E64
10:40:44.698 INFO: Source paths: Program.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, app.config, NuGet.config, packages.config
10:40:44.698 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
10:40:44.699 INFO: Index files
10:40:44.703 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
10:40:44.703 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js
10:40:44.710 DEBUG: Language of file 'Program.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
10:40:44.711 DEBUG: Language of file 'Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
10:40:44.728 INFO: Analyzer working directory does not exist
10:40:44.729 INFO: 2 files indexed
10:40:44.737 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
10:40:44.741 DEBUG: Code colorizer, supported languages: 
10:40:45.768 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:40:45.768 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
10:40:45.779 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
10:40:45.781 DEBUG: Sensors : Lines Sensor -> SCM Sensor -> C# -> Coverage Report Import -> Coverage Report Import -> Unit Test Results Import -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> Code Colorizer Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
10:40:45.782 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
10:40:45.800 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=18ms
10:40:45.807 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
10:40:45.840 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=33ms
10:40:45.841 INFO: Sensor C#
10:40:45.859 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: true
10:40:47.974 INFO: SonarAnalyzer for C# version 1.20.1.1275
10:40:48.355 INFO: 0/2 files analyzed, starting to analyze: C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs
10:40:49.606 ERROR: Failed to analyze the file: C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs
10:40:49.611 ERROR: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Software Development\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs' is denied.
10:40:49.611 ERROR:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
10:40:49.611 ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
10:40:49.611 ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
10:40:49.611 ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.CompilationHelper.GetSolutionFromFiles(String filePath, Encoding encoding, AnalyzerLanguage language)
10:40:49.612 ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.Program.RunAnalysis(ScannerAnalyzerConfiguration conf)
10:40:49.637 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:40:49.637 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:40:49.637 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:40:49.637 INFO: Total time: 9.694s
10:40:49.769 INFO: Final Memory: 47M/254M
10:40:49.769 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:40:49.770 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The .NET analyzer failed with exit code: 1 - Verify that the .NET Framework version 4.5.2 at least is installed.
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.analyze(CSharpSensor.java:159)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:104)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
10:40:49.806 ERROR: 
10:40:49.806 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
10:40:49.946  Creating a summary markdown file...
10:40:49.948  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: We haven't seen this problem before and can't repro it either. Could you check with the Resource Monitor which processes are associated with the handle `C:\TF\16\35\src\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs`?

Comment: Using Process Monitor I can see that the following processes are accessing the file (in sequence):

MSBuild.exe
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe
java.exe
SonarAnalyzer.Scanner.exe --> ACCESS DENIED

Comment: I tried to revert to SonarQube v 6.1 and I realized that the issue is not related to SonarQube version but to C# plugin version. The issue appears after installing C# plugin v. 5.5.1.522, no matter which version of SonarQube I'm using. With C# plugin v. 5.5.0.475 it works fine in SonarQube 6.2 as well. I did not realize it in first place, since I upgraded both SonarQube and C# plugin at the same time.

Comment: Are you building your solution with msbuild12 or msbuild14? Can you check if `C:\TF\16\35\src\Net Projects\Solutions\Test\TestSonarQube\Program.cs` is readonly or not?

Comment: I'm using msbuild14. The files are all read-only. I tried now (following your tip) to remove the read-only flag and the issue disappeared. Unfortunately this cannot be the solution, because files are controlled by TFS and read-only flag is important for TFS to keep track of what has been changed without checking it out (outside Visual Studio).

Comment: It seems to me that the Scanner for MsBuild can't find the output files of an msbuild14 analysis, therefore decides to run in msbuild12 mode. And you're running into this issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1122. Could you please check the full analysis log for any clues? You can increase the verbosity by specifying `/d:sonar.verbose=true` on the `begin` step. Also, please double check the path of msbuild.

Comment: I could not find any evidence of usage of msbuild12 in the log but I added the full analysis log to the original question. I double checked the msbuild path and it looks correct to me. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Tamas: Did you have a chance to look at the log I attached?

Comment: `"SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: true`" means that we're reading the files one-by-one in the `end` phase, and as the files are `readonly` we run into this bug: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1122. The fix will be part of C# plugin 5.6. I don't get how you end up running into this with msbuild14. Could you share the folder structure of your `.sonarqube` folder?